# Filtering by Field on Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I've got two models that are related to one another

```
class IndustryService(models.Model):    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    pricingisarate = models.BooleanField(default=False) 

class UserService(models.Model):  
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    title = models.ForeignKey(IndustryService, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

Within a view, I'm trying to develop a queryset of UserService instances that

a) belongs to a user

b) on the foreign key, has `pricingisarate == True`

I've tried the following query, but it doesn't work:

```
 services = UserService.objects.filter(user=user, industryservice__pricingisarate__is=True)
```

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: No, sorry. This query doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
services = UserService.objects.filter(user=user, title__pricingisarate=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filtering Foreign-Keys fields by using double underline between foreign-key defined name and sub field name that you want filtering by this, for your case it is similar below:

```
title__pricingisarate
```

And your query must change as below:

```
services = UserService.objects.filter(user=user, title__pricingisarate=True)
```

Some [formal examples of Django about this article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) is available...

Answer (score 0):

```
services = UserService.objects.filter(user=user, title__pricingisarate=True)
```

Because `UserService` is related to `IndustryService` model using lookup title.

Please refer to this link -  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships